# VSCode is not saving changes in Jupyter Notebook (unless I run the cells with changes)

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ide

I've been losing changes I've made to some of my cells because although I saved the notebook file, I didn't actually run the cell (this is for both code and markdown cells). And when I close the file down there is no warning of the sort "do you want to save changes?".

I know the workaround is to just run cells before saving. But it's just not a robust working setup.

Anyone got solutions? I would even switch editor to something with a similar feel if there's an alternative.

Comment: I got a similar problem but in my case it losses any change even though the cell was run. The problem happens from time to time, not always. I don't know what trigger this error.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, checkout the github response [(link)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1677#issuecomment-754784109)

In USER settings (~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json) include:

```
"jupyter.experiments.optInto": [
    "CustomEditor"
]
```

Helped for me.